# Can a company sell mobile applications to its customers (not In House) using the iOS Developer Enterprise Program?

Tags: ios, distribution

Additionally, is there an agreement that Apple makes the company sign in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

No. The Enterprise program is for a company to develop in-house apps for internal use.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's only for in-house apps between employees and people within the company. I'm pretty sure you need to agree to the conditions of it as well.

Answer (score 1):

**No, it's only for in-house apps.** Also, yes there is a usage terms agreement.

Answer (score 0):

All iOS Developer enrollments, including both company and enterprise,  require agreeing to the terms of a very long and explicit agreement as a required part of the enrollment process.  Have your company lawyer read and interpret it for you.

Comment: Is there a link I can download this agreement?

Comment: I agree that it's always good to have a lawyer read anything you might sign, I'll say that Apple does a pretty good job making the various developer agreements easy to read and understand. You should be able to see the agreement if you start [here](http://developer.apple.com/programs/start/standard/) and follow the steps to enroll in the program of your choice.